# Rocky npm package watch script causes error

Tags: node.js, gulp

[image: Editor screenshot]

I downloaded [Rocky](https://github.com/codingphasedotcom/rocky) from GitHub which requires me to run:

```
npm install
npm run watch
```

I installed node.js, latest Python files, and VS Build Tools however I cannot proceed from here.

Here is the error log:

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Joseph\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'watch' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v9.3.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]
5 info lifecycle RockyBoy@1.0.0~prewatch: RockyBoy@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle RockyBoy@1.0.0~watch: RockyBoy@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle RockyBoy@1.0.0~watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle RockyBoy@1.0.0~watch: PATH: C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Projects\Web App\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Python27;C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle RockyBoy@1.0.0~watch: CWD: C:\Projects\Web App
10 silly lifecycle RockyBoy@1.0.0~watch: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gulp' ]
11 silly lifecycle RockyBoy@1.0.0~watch: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle RockyBoy@1.0.0~watch: Failed to exec watch script
13 verbose stack Error: RockyBoy@1.0.0 watch: `gulp`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid RockyBoy@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Projects\Web App
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Joseph\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch"
18 verbose node v9.3.0
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error RockyBoy@1.0.0 watch: `gulp`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the RockyBoy@1.0.0 watch script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Your question is very poorly worded. Please read the SO Guidelines before posting.

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your question after identifying the npm package you're referring to. You might like to check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also some pointers on how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Understanding these will hopefully drastically increase the chances of people being able to help you. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was my first time ever posting. Do you know what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: I came to this for help and all I got was bad criticism from you sparkplug. Thanks for not helping whatsoever.